# Google Cloud SQL always on

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I've a Google Cloud SQL instance with followings settings:

- pricingPlan: PER_USE
- activationPolicy: ON_DEMAND

I have added an IPv4 address.

I have verified with Google Cloud SQL API that the settings are well saved.

Problem: I do not have any active query but the instance never stop, charging me 24h per day.

I'm sure the connections don't come from me. I've deleted all authorized networks and I've reboot the instance, but I still always have 1 active connection.

Is the someone that have the same problem?

Many thanks,

Loic

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the `active connections` chart from the Google Developers console?

Note that if the Cloud SQL instance is running, you'll always have at least 1 active connection because that's the one that Google uses to monitor your instance. This connection will not keep your instance running.

Comment: Sure here is a screenshot : https://www.dropbox.com/s/t1xr8ntkf24ncg3/Capture%20d%27%C3%A9cran%202015-09-07%2011.59.16.png?dl=0

Answer (score 2):

As Juan Munoz says, there is always 1 active connection while your instance is running, but that won't make your instance keep running.

If you are being charged continuously even though you have set `activationPolicy=ON_DEMAND` and have no authorized networks you might want to check if you have an authorized App Engine app and whether *it* is connecting to your instance.

Also your instance will be constantly active, regardless of activationPolicy, if it is a replication master. Because the slave keeps a connection open the master will never be able to shut down. I doubt this is occurring here as I imagine the slave's connection would have appeared on your active connections graph.

Comment: thank yuo for your answer. 
I've change the file replication system to asynchron.
And I've disable the backups.

I've always 1 connection but it seems it's normal. The google support doesn't not provide any help. I think I will migrate outside Google SQL, because i's more expansive that a dedicate server.